# How to generate password protected csv file by using php

Tags: php, csv

I have to generate password protected csv file through php script. Generation of csv file through php script is easy and I have done this, but I am facing problem in making password protected this file. Please suggest how this can be done.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot simply password protect .csv file without converting it in another format such as .xls because it is visible with any text editor.

However, you can create the .csv file with PHP, after that you can put it into a zip archive with password also with PHP. That is one way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.

Unlike Office documents or Zip files, CSV is a pure text format with no security provisions whatsoever.

Comment: It is possible to encrypt the files and decrypt them using PHP if he only plans to use them within his own application, but wishes them to be encrypted whilst stored.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is to encrypt/decrypt your cvs files if you really care about the data but again then csv readers won't be able to read your csv files unless its decrypted.